# Can't Decompile .NET-built executable

Tags: c#, .net

I have an executable that requires .NET Framework to run; I have used reflector and some popular decompilers but the can't read the executable;

Here's the manifest gotten using Resource Hacker ;

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<assembly xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1" manifestVersion="1.0">
  <assemblyIdentity version="1.0.0.0" name="MyApplication.app"/>
  <trustInfo xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v2">
    <security>
      <requestedPrivileges xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v3">
        <requestedExecutionLevel level="asInvoker" uiAccess="false"/>
      </requestedPrivileges>
    </security>
  </trustInfo>
</assembly>
```

Can someone tell me the appropriate tool to use to decompile this assembly or executable? It requires `.NET` to run. Thanks.
I'm using this for educational purposes.

Comment: "but the can't read the executable" - any errors or warnings that might give any info??

Comment: Thanks, everyone. De4Dot did it.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It sounds like the the executable may have been obfuscated (protected) against .NET decompliation/reflection tools such as Reflector, ILSpy, dotPeek etc.

There are several tools available that perform such protection, including [Babel.NET](http://www.babelfor.net) and [Dotfuscator](http://preemptive.com/products/dotfuscator/overview).

You could try [de4dot](https://github.com/0xd4d/de4dot), which can 'deobfuscate' .NET assemblies that have been protected using several tools, including Crypto Obfuscator, Dotfuscator, NET Reactor and SmartAssembly.

Answer (score 3):

That is a clickonce app.

First, you need to extract the content (dont recall if the '.app' is a CAB or ZIP).
Then use Reflector or your favourite decompiler.

Comment: The app is a .exe; How do I extract?

Comment: No, the clickonce installer is probably an EXE.

Answer (score -1):

If Reflector can't decompile it, then it must have been obfuscated with a code obfuscation tool such as [SmartAssembly](http://www.red-gate.com/products/dotnet-development/smartassembly/) or [Dotfuscator](http://preemptive.com/products/dotfuscator/overview).

In this case, there is no way to decompile the application.

Comment: No way? The runtime is able to get the IL somehow, so I have to be able to do the same.

Comment: That is what you'd think... But these tools are called obfuscators for a reason. They break decompilers. That is why Reflector cannot decompile anything that is obfuscated with a proper tool. Thanks for downvoting by the way!

Comment: I didn't downvote, but you're right they are called obfuscators for a reason: and that's because they make decompilation *harder, but not impossible*. If you can run the code, you can decompile it (at least on PCs). It's as simple as that and no tool can change that.

Comment: Reflector is basically pattern-matching against IL patterns that the C# compiler emits, so it's very easy for obfuscators to confuse Reflector and prevent decompilation.
However, other decompilers such as ILSpy can deal with pretty much any IL code (though the resulting C# code may get quite unreadable).
And extracting the IL is always possible as svick says: if the .NET runtime can do it, a decompiler could do it as well. It just needs to handle invalid constructs in the assembly the same way the .NET runtime does.